# jquery delay between html and group of calls

Tags: jquery

Trying to figure this out and haven't had much success.  First and foremost I want to make sure that the html call has completed before the fadein and two functions are called below it.

Secondly, I want to add in a delay, say 200, after the html loading and before the fadein and two functions.

I can add .delay(200) to the end of the html call, but it only delays the fadein... the other two functions run earlier... I all three to run at the same time. I am trying to mimic the same result if I were using load and wrapping these three in a function call.

```
if (response.success) {

    $myElem = $('#show-edit'); //performance
    $myElem.fadeOut('fast', function(){                 
        $myElem.html('someText');

        //once html added do these
        $myElem.fadeIn('fast');

        showSelect();

        // show success toast
        toastr.info('User \'<b>'+response.username+'</b>\' has been deleted.', 'Success');

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `timeOut`, or you could use `delay()` with a `queue()`, but it's not really any easier :

```
if (response.success) {
    $('#show-edit').fadeOut('fast', function(){                 
        var self = $(this);
        self.html('someText');
        setTimeout(function() {
           self.fadeIn('fast');
           showSelect();
           toastr.info('User \'<b>'+response.username+'</b>\' has been deleted.', 'Success');
        },200)
    });
}
```

Comment: That works perfect!  This response is coming from a button click inside a modal.  The modal fading is set to fast (200) so fading out of the modal and #show-edit happens at the same time... then there is a slight pause, then fading of the content I wanted... perfect.  Is there no check needed for html() to ensure its contents have loaded before the setTimeout runs?

Comment: Nope, html() is synchronous, so there is no callback needed.